# How to Insert or Update table in C# with MS Access Database

Tags: c#, ms-access-2007, oledb

I was using SQL Server database then I export SQL database to MS Access and  use the database in C# project.

Now When I try to insert or Update Data in any table it give an error message about the incorrect query. Which is "Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement."

My Query in C# is :

```
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Engr. Mac\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\SGM\SGM\SGdb.mdb");
OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand("", con);
con.Open();

com.CommandText = "INSERT INTO newOrder (Order_No, Customer_No, Issue_Date, Delivery_Date, Order_Type,Total_Weight) Values('" + orderbol.OrderNo + "', '" + orderbol.CustomerN0 + "', '" + orderbol.IssueDate + "', '" + orderbol.DlvryDate + "', '" + orderbol.OrdrType + "','"+0+"')";
if(com.ExecuteNonQuery()>0)
{
    con.Close();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: it is very likely your problem will disappear if you used SQL Parameters;  see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15346322/1070452  it is **very** hard to search SO for a SQL answer which does not include SQLparams.

Comment: i have also used sql parameters in query   but  didn't work

Comment: try an '#' arround the date fields like: "VALUES (#'" + orderbol.IssueDate + "'#)"

Answer (score 1):

it's a good practice to use command parameters instead of concatenate strings, you can find here an example:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbparameter(v=vs.110).aspx

however, try to add this in your example:

```
com.CommandText = "INSERT INTO newOrder (Order_No, Customer_No, Issue_Date, Delivery_Date, Order_Type,Total_Weight) Values(@1,@2,@3,@4,@5,@6);";
        com.Parameters.Add("@Order_No", OleDbType.Char, 1).Value = "1";
        com.Parameters.Add("@Customer_No", OleDbType.Char, 1).Value = "2";
        com.Parameters.Add("@Issue_Date", OleDbType.Char, 1).Value = "3";
        com.Parameters.Add("@Delivery_Date", OleDbType.Char, 1).Value = "4";
        com.Parameters.Add("@Order_Type", OleDbType.Char, 1).Value = "5";
        com.Parameters.Add("@Total_Weight", OleDbType.Char, 1).Value = "6";
```

and change the datatype of each parameter

Answer (score 0):

This works for me all the time.
For `db` I have it on the same directory for my application, but yours could be different so just change the value for `db` according to your setup.
As for the sql statement, I just put in a simple example for you to follow, replace the sql statement and also the part where it has the code `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue` according to your table columns because in my example code below, I am using a table of `fruit` with only two columns, an `id` column which is auto increment and a `fruitname` column for the fruit name.

```
string db = Application.StartupPath + "\\Database1.accdb";
string cs = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + db;
OleDbConnection c = new OleDbConnection(cs);

try
{
    c.Open();

    string s = "insert into fruit (fruitname) values (@fruitname)";
    using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(s, c))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fruitname", textBox1.Text.Trim());
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
catch (Exception)
{
    throw;
}
finally
{
    c.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

//Insert example

string _filename = @"C:\Automation\file.xls";

```
           _conn = "Provider=Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.12.0;" + @"Data Source=" + _filename4 + ";" + "Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";
            _connection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(_conn);

            // Use OledbCommand object to select all the data from sheet1 and execute a ExecuteNonQuery to import data into Book.mdb.

            _command = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand();

            _command.Connection = _connection;

            _command.CommandText = @"insert into [MS Access;Database=C:\Automation\file1.accdb].[tab1] select [f1],[f2],[f3],[f4] FROM [Sheet0$]";

            _connection.Open();

            _command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            _connection.Close();
```

//Update example

```
            connstr = "Provider=Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Automation\\IPR\\ipr.accdb";
            conn = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(connstr);
            cmdBulk = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand("update tab1,tab2 set tab1.f1 = tab2.f2 where tab1.f2 = tab2.f3", conn);
            conn.Open();
            cmdBulk.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
```