# Entering record to access database from 2nd form vb.net

Tags: database, ms-access, record

Dear Fellow VB programmers,

i'm currently have a problem adding a new record Ms. Access Database.

basicly, i made 2 forms

these 2 forms accessed the same database

-first form was succeed

-second form was also succeed, but when i check my database, the record from second form was created as new row. i wanted the data recorded in the same row

this is my code

```
Dim cb As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(da)
        Dim dsnewrow As DataRow
        dsnewrow = ds.Tables("GuestNumber").NewRow()
        dsnewrow.Item("GuestNumber") = txtGuestNumber.Text
        ds.Tables("GuestNumber").Rows.Add(dsnewrow)

        da.Update(ds, "GuestNumber")

        MsgBox("New Record added to database")


        btnAdd.Enabled = True
```

how to deal with this kind of problem? what kind of code shall i use?
thank you very much

Comment: Consider using [OleDb transactions](http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_net_db_transaction.html) where you run an insert SQL query that passes the form's values as parameters and then comimit. Alternatively, use `CommandText`. See this [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15346188/insert-data-into-oledb-table).

Comment: your code is actually adding new row! not update existing row!